# How do I create multiple abstract instances using a counter?

Tags: java, scope

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
     Button btn = new Button()
     {
         @Override
         public void click()
         {
             result = i;
         }
     };
     btn.setLocation(i * 30, 0);
     btn.setLabel("Option " + i);
}
```

However, since my `button` class is abstract, int `i` cannot be used because it is not listed as `final`. How do I enable the use of a counter in this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: use a `final int j = i` and use `j` in `click`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a final variable from the non-final one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  final int i0 = i;
  //etc.
```

Note that with Java 8+ the `final` modifier is optional.